# Navigator stack not working

Tags: dart, flutter, navigator

I have three screens. A, B and C. I push A, B, and C by using the following code. A is the first screen of the app.

```
class FadeInSlideOutRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {

  FadeInSlideOutRoute({WidgetBuilder builder, RouteSettings settings})
      : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      Widget child) {
    if (settings.isInitialRoute)
      return child;
    // Fades between routes. (If you don't want any animation,
    // just return child.)
    return new FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
  }
}
```

Screen declare in build method.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/B':
            return new FadeInSlideOutRoute(
              builder: (_) => new LoginScreen(),
              settings: settings,
            );
          case '/C':
            return new FadeInSlideOutRoute(
              builder: (_) => new ForgotPasswordScreen(),
              settings: settings,
            );
        }
        assert(false);
      },
      home: _LandingScreen(),
    );
  }
```

Now, I'm calling the following method to push new screens.

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/B');
```

After that

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/C');
```

**issue** is

when I'm pressing back of Android device from screen **C** it's come to screen **A** directly. But it should on screen **B**. Please help guys.

Comment: did you test on iOS ?

Comment: Noop, Just test it on an Android device.

Comment: maybe is not working at all , are you sure you are calling pushNamed instead pushReplacement?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling pushNamed as you can see above code snippet.

Comment: why do you call assert(false)

Comment: Is there anything wrong?